# Using logistic regression to detect fraudulent transactions

Tags: r, logistic, classification

I am using logistic regression (with R) for detecting fraudulent transactions. So far I am achieving a relatively good ratio of success (f-score).

However I have noticed something, once I have my model built, the threshold that gives me the best f-score is to consider something as fraudulent if the logit function is bigger than 0.059 (I started with 0.5).

For the record, I am using 7099 observations as training examples and 3042 as testing data, in total I am using 6 features/columns for prediction (planning to add a couple more)

Now my questions are the following

1. Am I doing something terribly wrong so that I have to use such a low limit to start labeling transactions as fraudulent?
2. That said, the vast majority of transaction are legitimate, does it justify the low threshold for the labeling (again, 0.059) ?
3. Would it be worth to explore other algs such random forest or neuronal networks?

Comment: (1-2) Your training examples fake/real are skewed thus the skewed threshold. You're probably not hired to optimize f-score :) Use a ROC or similar to evaluate every threshold and figure out what would make sense for your organization. Either you can catch a lot of cheaters (sensitivity) and accept the consequences of falsely accusing good costumers(1 - specificity) or reverse or some golden solution in between.
(3) Could work, remember you need to retrieve pseudo probabilities to quantify how sure you are of specific transaction is fake/real and to compare all models with ROC etc.

Comment: @SorenHavelundWelling thanks for the answer. The funny part is that using such a low threshold (later experimentation show that using 0.154 with certain features also works) gets me the following number: Out of 3042 testing examples (of which 42 are real), the system labels 139 as fraudulent, out of thos, 38 are indeed fraudulent. Sure that leaves me with 101 false positives, but that is acceptable (this will be eventually actioned by a human...). Now the question at this point is more academic I think, is it still valid to have such a low threshold?

Comment: You're welcome :) I think that should be all right, it is just an threshold. Try an alternative CV method and check if you get at similar result. Here's an example of how to use random forest and some diagnostics. 42 real testing? what about the rest?

Comment: @SorenHavelundWelling Did you forget to include the url for the random tree forest example? (thanks! :)